# XPS open source implementation?

Tags: c++, c, wpf, open-source, xps

Does any know of any C/C++ open source for XPS [XML Print Specification].

I found http://www.ndesk.org/Xps, but it is c# ...

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of functionality are you looking for?

To get raw access to the xml parts, you can use zlib and one of the myriad open source xml parsers.

Comment: @nixps, I think your idea is the best. I am now proceeding in that direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I know of two open source implementations of XPS parsing and rendering: there is GhostXPS for use with Ghostscript, and MuXPS. MuXPS is a fork of GhostXPS which is based on the MuPDF graphics library instead. MuXPS is still very new, but you can find the source in the MuPDF git repository.

Answer (score 1):

[Mighty Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_XML_Paper_Specification) says that [KDE Okular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okular) supports OpenXPS.

Comment: This doesn't really seem to answer the OP's question.  If I understand right, he's looking for a stand-alone library.  I note that http://okular.kde.org/formats.php does /not/ say which library is used for XPS.

Comment: The key is - it's **open source** - you can **read it**.

Answer (score 1):

Artifex has GhostXPS which can read XPS packages